# Evaluating sine of a squared angle in radians or degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm a high school math teacher teaching precalculus for the first time in a few years and we are in a trigonometry unit. The students have just learned the basic reciprocal relationships and the three versions of the Pythagorean identity ($\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta=1$).

The textbook had a homework problem asking to evaluate $\sin(\theta^2)$ for $\theta = \pi/3$ radians. Keeping the angle measure in radians I get $$\sin\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^2\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{9}\right) \approx 0.88967.$$ However, if I first convert the angle to degrees I get $$\sin\left((60^\circ)^2\right)=\sin(3600^\circ) = 0.$$

My gut tells me to keep the angle measure in radians, but I haven't been able to come up with a solid explanation for why. Any help or explanation of why one angle measure should be used over another would be helpful.

I also struggled with coming up with an identity-based direct evaluation of $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{9}\right)$. If there is any identity for sine of a product (something like $\sin(AB)$), that could also be helpful.

Comment: $sin$ requires a unitless input, which degrees isn't. Some programming languages have $sin$ for unitless (radian) input and another function, Sin maybe, for degrees input which converts to radians first. In your question they may have written $sin \theta ^2$ to mean $(sin\theta)^2$? Notation in trig can be very sloppy.

Comment: Evaluating in radians vs degrees is a bit like evaluating in fractions vs percentages. While $1/2$ is equivalent to $50\%$, you don't evaluate the square of the first as the square of the (numerical portion of) the latter: $(1/2)^2 \neq (50^2)\%$. It's helpful in that context to recall that "$\%$" is effectively shorthand for "$1/100$" ... so, $50\%$ isn't just *notation*, it's also a *calculation*; thus, "obviously", you don't square $50\%$ by squaring only the $50$. With angles, you can think of "$^\circ$" as shorthand for "$\pi/180$"; you don't square $60^\circ$ by squaring only the $60$.

Comment: Angles are not multiplicative, rather they are additive. In any case if two angles are to be multiplied, they must be done in radian, not in degrees. To check that they are not equal, $(60^\circ)^2=3600^\circ=20\pi\ne\frac{\pi^2}{9}$.

Comment: Also I don't think there is any simple formula for sine of product of two angles.

Comment: I also wonder if the problem is being misread as $\sin(\theta^2)$ while being intended as $\left(\sin\theta\right)^2$. There is no identity for $\sin(xy)$ in terms of trigs of $x$ and $y$ alone. (Short proof: $\sin(x)$, $\sin(y)$, $\cos(x)$, $\cos(y)$, etc, are $2\pi$-periodic in each of $x$ and $y$, while $\sin(xy)$ is not $2\pi$-periodic in either $x$ or $y$.) This notion has appeared on Math.SE a few times; try a site search. ... In the absence of such an identity, $\sin(\theta^2)$ is just a numerical calculation; it's not an expression you can generally hope to evaluate in your head.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it is a typo, that the high-school problem was to evaluate $\sin^2 \theta$ for $\theta = \pi/3$.  Please check.

Comment: For clarification, the problem did ask for both $\sin^2(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta^2)$. I appreciate your comments and will explain to my students to keep the angle in radians.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring an angle in degrees is a problem; angles in the degree measure are additive instead of multiplicative LIKE RADIANS.

That’s where the confusion when converting comes from.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Your suggested identity is invalid. In the test case $x=0$, we have $$\sin(0y)=\sin 0\cos y+\cos 0 \sin y \;\to\; 0=0+\sin y$$ which doesn't hold for every $y$. The identities typically called ["product-to-sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_identities) are like $$\sin x\sin y=\tfrac12(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y))$$ which are very different.

Comment: @Blue I deleted the part of the answer.